# Ubuntu running out of RAM and crashing and freezing because of it

Tags: ram, memory-usage, memory-leak

i have 32GB of RAM in my computer which should be more than enough as a web developer. i think adding more will only delay the out-of-ram issues.

i am experiencing issues on Ubuntu where chrome is taking up all the RAM. (this is determined by looking at the pre-installed task manager in Ubuntu).

when the RAM is fully consumed, it is clear Ubuntu starts to struggle to run:

- it take a long time to lock/unlock the computer
- there are random times the GUI is frozen for about a minute.

i have tried switching to using firefox... which is better with RAM consumption, but it is only delaying the out-of-ram issues.

i have tried closing all running applications, but i see that although RAM is freed up, but nothing works as well as a fresh reboot... and i dont think Ubuntu should be critically dependent on that (especially on hardware resources that are more than the average).

is there a way to limit the amount of RAM/resources used by applications/processes? i know chrome is known to consume RAM, but if the operating system doesn't impose any restriction on its resources then i have no choice except to reboot to use the computer.

... but i dont think that should be a solution to the problem of "browsing too much internet" (i dont use my computer for anything resource intensive like games).

info when running `free -m` on terminal.

```
~$ free -m
        total    used    free  shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:    32109    9584    9707     883       12817       21396
Swap:     975           0         975
```

Comment: How much swap do you have?

Comment: updated content with results of running `free -m`... instructions found from: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-check-swap-usage-command/